# How to @Override Comparator to make the Column in CellTable sort based on Integer not based on String (GWT)?

Tags: java, gwt

Ok, I got a Table with a list of No.

```
No
1
2
5
10
20
```

If i set `columnSortHandler` for the No column using String like this:

```
columnSortHandler.setComparator(noColumn, new Comparator<String[]>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2) {
            if (o1==o2) {
                  return 0;
            }


            if (o1 != null) {

                return (o2 != null) ? o1[0].compareTo(o2[0]) : 1;
            }
            return -1;
        }
    });
```

Then it won't sort like integer but like String. Ex: it will sort like this:

```
No
1
10
2
20
5
```

Then it is not correct.

So tried:

```
 columnSortHandler.setComparator(noColumn, new Comparator<String[]>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2) {
            if (o1==o2) {
                  return 0;
            }


            if (o1 != null) {

                return (o2 != null) ? Integer.parseInt(o1[0]).compareTo(Integer.parseInt(o2[0]) : 1;
            }
            return -1;
        }
    });
```

But compareTo does not apply for Integer.

So my question is

**How to @Override Comparator to make the Column in CellTable sort based on Integer not based on String (GWT)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Integer.valueOf()` as shown below

```
 return (o2 != null) ? Integer.valueOf(o1[0]).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(o2[0])) : 1;
```

instead of

```
 return (o2 != null) ? Integer.parseInt(o1[0]).compareTo(Integer.parseInt(o2[0]) : 1;
```

> Integer.parseInt() returns primitive int not wrapper Integer class.
>
> Cannot invoke compareTo(int) on the primitive type int

There are lots of ways to convert `String`into `Integer` wrapper class.

Try any one:

- Integer.valueOf(String)
- new Integer(String)
- Integer.getInteger(String)